# Stream of facebook updates

Tags: facebook, real-time, feed

I know about the real-time API, but I don't believe it has access to my news feed (yet?)
[https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/) (search for "News feed"). I just want to view all the messages to me just I would see on the facebook site.

I guess I could poll(undesired?) this feed to get access to the data. Just like tweetdeck does every minute. but I am wondering if this is really necessary to access this data? I am affraid that is the only option because otherwise tweetdeck would not do this excessive polling if you ask me.

Comment: what do you mean by "my news feed"?

Comment: @ifaour go to http://developers.facebook.com/docs/api/ and click on link for news feed which looks like https://graph.facebook.com/me/home?access_token=<...>. On that site you will see the feed when you are logged in.

Comment: I'm aware of that, but @Michael's answer got me confused as you are talking about *news feed* `/me/home` and his answer is talking about *your feeds* `/me/feed` which are totally different!

Comment: @ifaour you are right about the difference in feeds :). I did not notice that yet!

Comment: I guess you are aware that you **CAN** get real-time updates for your feeds `/me/feed` right? this is what I meant in my comment to @Michael's answer. Unfortunately *news feed* is not supported as mentioned in my Answer.

Comment: Yup I know about /me/feed but that's my feed :). I want to get status updates from my friends and then sent to my phone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *news feed* still ***not*** yet supported by the real-time updates method [`subscription`](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/subscription/):

> You **can't** subscribe to these user
>   connections **yet**: **home**, tagged, posts,
>   photos, albums, videos, groups, notes,
>   events, inbox, outbox, updates,
>   accounts

I suppose your best bet is to get the `offline_access` permission and polling Facebook's servers, but I would be *very* cautious when doing so!

Comment: The tweetdeck air client does polling every minute so I guess I am allowed to do that too. I don't even need to do it that much! P.S: I think I should award you bonus instead of nobody has the solution.

Comment: @Alfred, NO! each app has a [rate limit](http://dev.twitter.com/pages/rate-limiting) and most likely big twitter clients (maybe tweetdeck) have made agreements with Twitter to increase their limits..etc

Comment: it is a desktop app and (I believe) my computer itself makes the webrequests to facebook API.

Comment: @Alfred, I'm just commenting on your conclusion, just because tweetdeck is allowed to poll every minute (which is allowed by twitter by the way!) this shouldn't necessary apply to you doing the same with Facebook API! unfortunately I can't find any document about requests limitation...

Comment: you see it below 3 icons. Twitter uses push nowadays. But for example Buzz also polls. You see a timer from 1 minute to next request.

Answer (score 2):

I think what you are looking for is this: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed but you can only query it using an access token `?access_token=` that has been granted with the permission `read_stream`.

You will allways be asked before an application can do that.

You can see all the different permission types here: developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions and currently granted permissions here: www.facebook.com/settings/?tab=applications

-michael

Comment: I knew about this graph endpoint, but then I have to query/poll it. I hope I could get updated somehow when my feed changes?

Comment: Thats not possible. The only update you can get by facebook is via eMail.

Comment: so the only option is polling :$?

Comment: Im afraid so but for the time being there is no other way. :(

Comment: -1, 1) he can get an `offline_access`, 2) this `connection` can be subscribed to!